# Como criar uma pasta dentro do meu repositório no GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Como eu crio uma pasta no meu repositório para poder organizar os meus arquivos e não deixar tudo na mesma pasta do repositório no *GitHub*? isso pode ser feito criando a pasta usando a linha de comando ou no próprio *GitHub*?

Comment: Olá! Basta criar o diretório, colocar algum arquivo dentro (Git não versiona diretórios vazios), fazer o *commit* e depois o *push*. O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Oi! na pergunta eu não falo sobre esse problema em detalhes, mas no contexto são os mesmo passos da pergunta, então para ser preciso, eu sou novo no GitHub e não sei muita coisa, mas eu criei um repositório `pagina` e fiz upload de um arquivo do meu PC que é `index.html`, mas agora preciso criar uma pasta CSS para colocar meu arquivo `style.css` dentro dela.

Comment: Certo. Tentou fazer o que falei no meu comentário anterior?

Comment: Não! eu vou tentar me informar o que é um *commit* ou *push* para tentar fazer, pois eu não sei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta criar a pasta dentro do repositório local e colocar algum arquivo nela. Automaticamente o Git irá reconhecê-la e quando você executar o PUSH essa pasta bem como os arquivos e subpastas serão sincronizados com o seu repositório remoto.

**Vale ressaltar que o Git não monitora pastas e sim arquivos, por isso só serão criadas/sincronizadas pastas que contenham algum arquivo.**

Comment: Valeu! mas em relação ao GitHub não tem como fazer por lá?

Comment: No site não t conheço nenhuma opção. Talvez seja devido a premissa do GitHub de não controlar pastas e sim arquivos e que teoricamente as bases do seu projetos devem ser definidas localmente e só depois sincronizadas.

Answer (score 4):

Um repositório do Github é um repositório Git, e funciona exatamente como um, ou seja por linha de comando, mas também o site provê ferramentas para alguns dos principais comandos, que inclui criar arquivos, veja:

> Lembre-se: o Git não irá adicionar ao reposirtório pastas sem conteúdo!

1. Criando um arquivo em uma nova pasta pelo terminal

Em um repositório novo, crie uma pasta, navegue para ela:

```
git init
mkdir folder
cd folder
```

[image: A imagem mostra a execução dos comandos acima]

Em seguida crie um novo arquivo, abrindo o novo arquivo no Notepad é possível adicionar conteúdo, em seguida adicione o arquivo ao staging do Git e faça o commit:

```
New-Item file.txt
Notepad .\file.txt
git add *
git commit -m "New file"
```

[image: A imagem mostra a execução dos comandos acima]

O arquivo foi adicionado ao repositório, veja o log:

```
git log
```

[image: A imagem mostra a execução do comando acima]

2. Criando um arquivo em uma nova pasta pela interface web do Github

Clique no botão "Create new file" (1)

[image: A imagem mostra o botão a ser clicado: "Create new file"]

Na caixa de texto que irá abrir, digite o nome da pasta, ou seja "folder" (1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para indicar que está sendo criada uma nova pasta, digite "/" (caracter: barra), neste momento o texto digitado anteriormente será deslocado para a esquerda se tranformando em uma pasta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida digite o nome do arquivo que deseja criar, faça o comentário para o commit no campo em baixo da tela, quando terminar de digitar o conteúdo do arquivo e faça o commit clicando no botão.

Answer (score -3):

É exatamente como os colegas explicaram, o git não adciona pastas sem conteúdo algum,estou começando a ter mais prática sobre o git/github, mas eu passei pela mesma situação e o que fiz foi criar uma pasta e dentro dessa pasta criar um arquivo e depois  e depois todos os estágios básicos. git add . ou o arquivo especifico, git status, git commit -m "texto".

Answer (score -3):

Eu tive uma situação onde o computador não era meu e eu precisei criar um repositório do zero. Enviar os arquivos raiz foi simples. Agora para as pastas, eu abri a página de uploads e depois arrastei a pasta que eu queria (a pasta já com os arquivos dentro) do Explorer do Windows e soltei na página de uploads do GitHub.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

clique em "add file" e depois em "create a new file". O segredo está na hora de nomear o arquivo. Basta adicionar o nome da pasta que você quer "css" e colocar / aí você dá um nome para o arquivo depois da barra e salva que vai criar uma pasta automaticamente. Vai ficar tipo nomedorepositorio/css/nomequalquer. Pode sair e entrar na pasta e fazer o upload. Pode apagar o arquivo que você criou no começo para não atrapalhar.